# Customize order by in Gridview rows

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to order my gridview like the following

**Product Name**

```
FL - STATEWIDE (Primary)

FL - LEE COUNTY

FL - OKALOOSA COUNTY

MS - STATEWIDE (Primary)

MS - KENT COUNTY
```

I can not order by product. Because if the word **primary** is contained in the product name, then it should come first.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the expected order of the above products based on this condition: `if the word primary contains in the product name then it should come first.` ?

Comment: Yes, FL - STATEWIDE (Primary) is contains word primary so it comes first and followed by FL - LEE COUNTY and FL - OKALOOSA COUNTY

Comment: Can you advise what is the data source ... Table, Collection List... etc.

Comment: @ChrisHammond it is data table

Comment: Can you list the expected order that you need the list

Comment: @ChrisHammond I have described in the question, based on state(FL and MS) it should order. In that, in the product name the word "Primary" present then it should comes first in the state. You can see FL - STATEWIDE (Primary) and MS - STATEWIDE (Primary)

Comment: @Golda ... See Answer below :)

Comment: @Golda Where is the data actually stored... Is it in a Database, if so,  rather than my answer below to use LINQ on the datatable, can you not just ORDER it on the SQL Select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have read in your datatable, you can then use LINQ to order it

```
        dtbl = (
                 from item in dtbl.AsEnumerable()
                 select item
               ).OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Product Name").Contains("Primary") ? 0 : 1).
                 ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("Product Name")).CopyToDataTable();
```

Output

FL - STATEWIDE (Primary)

MS - STATEWIDE (Primary)

FL - LEE COUNTY

FL - OKALOOSA COUNTY

MS - KENT COUNTY

If you need to order by State first (with Primary at the top)

```
        dtbl = (
                 from item in dtbl.AsEnumerable()
                 select item
               ).OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Product Name").Substring(0,2))
                 ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("Product Name").Contains("Primary") ? 0 : 1).
                 ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("Product Name")).CopyToDataTable();
```

Output

FL - STATEWIDE (Primary)

FL - LEE COUNTY

FL - OKALOOSA COUNTY

MS - STATEWIDE (Primary)

MS - KENT COUNTY

Comment: i am facing one problem MS - STATEWIDE (Primary) next value is **MISSISSIPPI**. How to achieve this. It first display MISSISSIPPI next MS - STATEWIDE (Primary)

Comment: @Golda Unless there is some consistency in the names, then a basic sorting routine will not work and therefore you would need to create a custom [IComparer Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.100).aspx)